# Access GoogleMap from different class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-adapter

I'm building an app with Google maps and I'm using map fragment. Also I'm using an autocompletetextview with cursoradapter implementation. 
I'm trying to implement the

`onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

event in my adapter class - but I'm running into a problem when I try to put add a marker on the map from the adapter class.

I have tried the following solutions:

1. I've built an interface containing a function that should return the map object and passed it to the adapter constructor but I get null pointer upon click.
2. I've tried passing the map fragment, and calling getMap() BUT google says this method is deprecated.
3. I've tried passing the GoogleMap object, but I'm getting null pointer exception.

I understand that the easiest solution would be placing the listener for the onclick event in the main activity but wouldn't be design smart.

**UPDATE** 
i have made it work with an interface passed to the class but is there any more design wise solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. & 3. you should really post some code and the stacktrace.
2. Replacement for getMap() ist [getMapAsync()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync%28com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback%29).

Comment: I will but it's just returnes null pointer from the call to add marker and napa sync doesn't return map object as it seems